# Type mismatch for extending classes

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement a HashMap. I've already implemented an ArraySet and a KeyValuePair with the following signatures:

```
public class ArrayList<E> implements List<E>
public class ArraySet<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Set<E>
class KeyValuePair<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V>
public class HashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>
```

For the `entrySet` method I have the following:

```
public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
    Set<Entry<K,V>> entries = new ArraySet<KeyValuePair<K,V>>();
}
```

But this gives `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArraySet<KeyValuePair<K,V>> to Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` despite the fact ArraySet implements Set and KeyValuePair implements Map.Entry. I can't change the return type as it's part of the Map interface.

Comment: a `Set<Entry<K,V>>` is not the same as `Set<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` (or `ArraySet<KeyValuePair<K,V>>` as coded) - like a box of fruits not being the same as a box of apples (first one could also contain oranges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign a `new Set<KeyValuePair<K,V>>()` to a variable declared as `Set<Entry<K,V>>` for a good reason. If you could, you would then be able to call `entries.add(<some item that is a Set.Entry but not a KeyValuePair>)` and that would obviously lead to trouble.

To fix your immediate problem, you need to assign a compatible type, so do this:

```
Set<Entry<K,V>> entries = new ArraySet<Entry<K,V>>();
```

and then you can add `KeyValuePair` items to your `entries` set.

However, your code still has some problems:

1. You should avoid calling your classes the same name as well-known classes from package `java.util`. This can lead to confusion when someone reads your code. Choose names other than ArrayList and HashMap. You already have an ArraySet, so why not ArrayMap.
2. Avoid duplication. You can see the implementation of HashSet in the Java API source: it's actually just a HashMap with dummy values. You can do the same in your code, implementing ArraySet in terms of ArrayMap.
3. Your ArraySet implements both the `List` and `Set` interfaces. You cannot correctly implement both interfaces, as they have conflicting contracts. You shouldn't extend ArrayList. Your ArraySet is a Set, it's not really a List. It's implemented using a List, so you should use a private List member in your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For my assignment I have to implement all the java.utils I wish to use myself, so using the same names makes things easier as I can't use the java.util versions anyway. For points 2 and 3 I've quickly made the ArraySet class purely for this return type, I'll take a look at HashSet for future use though as I'm aware ArraySet isn't particularly efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ArraySet<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements Set<E>
```

ArraySet does both implementing ArrayList and Set.

```
Set<Entry<K,V>> entries = new ArraySet<KeyValuePair<K,V>>();
```

Where can Set store ArrayList members ?

So, You cannot write the above code.
Instead you can do

```
Set<Entry<K,V>> entries = new Set<KeyValuePair<K,V>>();
```

Because you can also do, since KeyValue pair only implements Entry and don't do anything else.

```
Entry<K,V> entries = new KeyValuePair<K,V>();
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. There's nothing I can see wrong with ArraySet and your suggestion does not work.